# UUID example java

Tags: java

UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll(“\W”, “”);

What does the meaning of “\W” in the above statement?
Is it replace non-alphanumerics?
This replaceAll method changing the entire generated random value. 
Let’s say 
1. UUID.randomUUID().toString()
2. UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll(“\W”, “”);
Both 1& 2 values are totally different 
Please advise .
Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: What do you think `randomUUID()` is doing? Especially if you call it twice.

Comment: Can't you just test these code snippets locally and see for yourself what they are doing?  Replacing `\\W+` with empty string will in fact strip off non alphanumerics, which in this case would be the hyphen separators of the UUID.

Comment: Have you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Java API Documentation states:

```
String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

*Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.*

As you see, first argument is a **regular expression**. To see list of available ways of using regular expressions, you can look up `Pattern` class in documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

You will find that `\\W` looks for a non-word character. In your particular example it means replacing "`-`" with "", in other words, you get rid of all "`-`" from `UUID` passed to that method.